# Offline Address Book Synchronization Troubles

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm unable to access the oab.xml file on my Exchange 2010 CAS.  I've recreated the OAB virtual directory and it didn't make a difference.  Using "Effective Permissions", I've verified that I have rights to view oab.xml, but any attempt to download it remotely (from Outlook 2010 or IE 9) is refused by IIS.  Here are the pertinent log entries --

```
2012-04-20 18:38:41 12.3.4.56 HEAD /OAB/2c34c9f5-5521-4c8c-b684-538df815052a/oab.xml - 80 - 12.3.4.78 Microsoft+BITS/7.5 401 2 5 203
2012-04-20 18:38:44 12.3.4.56 HEAD /OAB/2c34c9f5-5521-4c8c-b684-538df815052a/oab.xml - 80 - 12.3.4.78 Microsoft+BITS/7.5 401 2 5 31
2012-04-20 18:38:44 12.3.4.56 HEAD /OAB/2c34c9f5-5521-4c8c-b684-538df815052a/oab.xml - 80 domain\jdoe 12.3.4.78 Microsoft+BITS/7.5 403 1 64 31
2012-04-20 18:38:46 12.3.4.56 HEAD /OAB/2c34c9f5-5521-4c8c-b684-538df815052a/oab.xml - 443 - 12.3.4.78 Microsoft+BITS/7.5 401 2 5 203
2012-04-20 18:38:48 12.3.4.56 HEAD /OAB/2c34c9f5-5521-4c8c-b684-538df815052a/oab.xml - 443 - 12.3.4.78 Microsoft+BITS/7.5 401 2 5 31
2012-04-20 18:38:48 12.3.4.56 HEAD /OAB/2c34c9f5-5521-4c8c-b684-538df815052a/oab.xml - 443 - 12.3.4.78 Microsoft+BITS/7.5 401 1 2148074254 0
2012-04-20 18:38:48 12.3.4.56 HEAD /OAB/2c34c9f5-5521-4c8c-b684-538df815052a/oab.xml - 443 domain\jdoe 12.3.4.78 Microsoft+BITS/7.5 403 1 5 218
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this one.  I thought to try to access the oab.xml file from the server so that I'd see the detailed error information.  It turned out that the issue was with the Handler Mappings in IIS.  Steps to resolve were as follows:

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the the `OAB\<GUID>` virtual directory.
2. On the Features page, double-click the **Handler Mappings** feature.
3. On the Handler Mappings page, in the Actions pane, click **Edit Feature Permissions**.
4. In the Edit Handler Mappings dialog box, I checked **Scripts** (**Read** was already checked).